# Change different windows in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

First, the first winodw can show. And I try to click the button from first window, and then I want it change to another window. But it show the Error Msg:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\try1_byHank.py", line 61, in <lambda>
    self.button1["command"] =  lambda: self.controller.self.show_frame("PageOne")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1898, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: self
```

The Code: Please~~ help me find out the problem~~~~ thanks a lot!!!

```
from Tkinter import *

class SampleApp(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StarPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frame[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frame[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.title = Label(self)
        self.title["text"] = "Please Click Button"
        self.title["font"] = "Times New Romand",22
        self.title["width"] = 26
        self.title["height"] = 2        
        self.title.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.button1 = Button(self)
        self.button1["text"] = "Click Me"
        self.button1["font"] = "Times New Romand",17
        self.button1["command"] =  lambda: self.controller.self.show_frame("PageOne")
        self.button1.grid(row=1,column=0)               

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    root.title('test')
    root.geometry('454x300+100+100') 
    app = StartPage(parent=root,controller=root)
    app.mainloop()



class PageOne(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller): 
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.title1 = Label(self)
        self.title1["text"] = "Hello"
        self.title1["bg"] = "blue"
        self.title1["font"] = "Times New Romand",20
        self.title1["width"] = 32
        self.title1["height"] = 2
        self.title1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=10,sticky="nw")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    root.title('test Window') 
    app = PageOne(parent=root,controller=root)
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

I think the problem maybe is at the code:

```
self.button1["command"] =  lambda: self.controller.self.show_frame("PageOne")
```

And I try to change the code to:

```
self.button1["command"] =  lambda: self.controller.show_frame("PageOne")
```

The Error msg become:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1536, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\try1_byHank.py", line 61, in <lambda>
    self.button1["command"] =  lambda: self.controller.show_frame("PageOne")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1898, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: show_frame
```

Why the show_frame() can work in SampleApp Class, but can't work in StartPage Class...

Comment: You've problem with your classes. You are trying to access to the function `show_frame` that is on the `SampleApp` class from the `StartPage` class.

Comment: The error is telling you _precisely_ what the problem is. Read the error message closely. You have a second problem where you try to reference `self.controller.self...`.

Comment: @Borja: no, that's not the problem. It's _a_ problem, but not _the_ problem in this question.

Comment: First, thank you so much to answer me. I've refleshed my question. I add the show_frame() to the StartPage class, But it still can't work~~